# Regex needed for matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have this string

```
s = [notneedtext#neededtext, notneedtext#neededtext, ...]
```

What regex should I use to keep the needed text only of each element (without `#`) and cut the not needed part?

Comment: Can `#` be inside the `neededtext` as well?

Comment: I mention it in (). Nope # shouldnt be inside @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: I mean can there be two or more `#` characters?

Comment: Yes their number is random @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should show a minimal understanding of the problem by including their attempt in the question, the desired output and the problems encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `neededtext` does not contain commas, all you need is

```
(?<=#)([^,]*)(?=(,|\]))
```

- The first part `(?<=#)` requires that the needed text is preceded by `#`
- The middle part `([^,]*)` captures a sequence of zero or more characters other than comma
- The final part `(?=(,|\]))` requires that the sequence is ended in a comma or a square bracket.

Comment: I think | is not valid cause it shows error @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @user2598911 It works perfectly, [here is a link to a demo](http://ideone.com/ShmT4V).

Comment: In your answer here you forgot to add another \. it needs \\ and it works. Thanks

Comment: @user2598911 I did not put the second slash on purpose, to show the regex itself. The slash is needed for Java compiler, not for the regex engine, because anything that goes in double quotes must escape its backslashes. In this case it wouldn't be bad, but in regexes with more slashes doubling each one hampers readability. Anyway, I'm glad that it worked for you!